# Is there any elegant way to cancel/stop a long running thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I know about CancellationToken support in TPL, but (IMO) that could work only if I have appropriate token.ThrowifCancellationRequested(), which is not possible in my scenario.

Is there any other elegant way (other than aborting the thread altogether) to achieve this?

I do not care about the transactional state of the thread.
I do not care at what state the thread is stopped/cancelled.

Thanks for your interest!

More Details:
I need to spawn a new thread (Task/Threadpool/Thread) to call an API which calls multiple stored procedures to fetch near 1million records, and then it does some decoration (business calculation) on each of the records.
In the end, this API returns a data table which is a business significant report.
I want to give the users the option to cancel this processing mid-way, if needed. For instance, if wrong of set of filters are set.
The API *only* does the read-only operations, so no transaction management is required.

Comment: If you don't have the token, what *do* you have? Just a handle to the thread?

Comment: Is this a situation where you're calling an external library from a thread, and the external library has no cancellation method?

Comment: Slightly rephrased: please give more details about your scenario.  The question is too vague as-is IMHO to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Ic. I have added more details above. I am flexible to having a token/ handle of a thread. Just need an elegant way to call the time taking processing in a separate thread, with an option to cancel it.

Comment: I'm not clear on why the cancellation token approach isn't the right one (also, what framework version are you using?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I can not use cancellation token because I can not modify the API that generates report. I only have control to invoke that API in a separate thread.

Comment: In that case, it's tricky, since there's no good way to clean up the mess left by terminating the job - it may not need transactional guarantees, but you might care if all of the database connections are leaked when aborts occur.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: that is a useful point actually (cleaning of open connections). +1.

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly, you should use built-up methods in a Task class via a cancellation token, or use cancel a background worker. Or, you may try to use a `volatile` bool to check if a user request has been cancelled. However, `volatile` bools aren't behaving consistently across different architectures (single/multi processor). Alternatively you may use `*ResetEvent`s to indication that cancel was called. This all needs to be done in the API itself, otherwise how would it know when to check for a cancellation condition? You won't be able to cancel it gracefully.

Of course, do not ever call `Abort` on a thread - that's evil and may leave the whole application in an undefined state, unless you plan to restart whole application, don't call it.

#### Bonus suggestion

Also consider doing all the processing work on the database side. Do not bring more than a very small amount of records to the client side, say 1k is a good practical threshold. Consider a situation where many users request different reports that all load a server *that* much - this doesn't scale well. Moreover servers are very efficient with data processing and they have data at theirs side - lots of optimisation is done (CPU line caching, fast memory access etc.).